# redirect to dynamic URL have PHP content in URL

Tags: php

how to redirect form to dynamic URL with dynamic content

I start in php mode echo string  and I want variables in strings

i am sorry if its not clear . I am new to php I work for servers and network recently found intrest in web designing
rephrasing question as this is first time 
i am  registered to a forum for first time recently . now i learned how to show code .
i am learning php for hobby this is a project i am making for myself. for learning

```
<a href="modify_pages.php?pages=<?php echo urlencode($current_pages["id"]); ?>"> modify Page</a>
```

works fine but copied only sample code to keep it simple i am not sure about question length 
if i am supposed to enter whole code please let me know for future if it is reqiured to enter 
full code

```
<?php
//current page id and current Step id is data  from sql database table for this page 

function redirect_to($new_location) {
          header("Location: ".$new_location);
                 exit;
   }

 if ($some_var1==$some_var2)
   {
      redirect_to("edit_pages.php?pages=<?php echo urlencode($current_step["id"])?>");
   } else {
    redirect_to("edit_pages.php?pages=<?php echo urlencode($current_pages["id"])?>");

 ?>
```

basic problem i am facing is is it possible to use phptag or script logic in quotation marks ""

html " ;  ?>

PHP《HTML《PHP》》nesting php and html

I am really looking for  help(workaround)
 because if we can use php logics in quotation that will help me very much to shorten my codes in future

not sure how to make this working please help me with this thankful for all helps

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<?php
     $variable = 'Maths';
?>
form_page.php?subject=<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

output will be

```
 form_page.php?subject=Maths
```

Comment: function i am using to redirect is already in in php mode    
$message = "page update failed here at this place";
   redirect_to("new_pages.php?some variables..");

Comment: So what? It seems your method's not working... What's your question?!